# Using generics in Unity ... InvalidCastException

Tags: .net, generics, configuration, inversion-of-control, unity-container

My interface definition is:
          public interface IInterface where T:UserControl

My class definition is:
          public partial class App1Control : UserControl, IInterface

The unity section of my app.config looks as below:

```
  <unity>
    <typeAliases>
      <typeAlias alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
      <typeAlias alias="myInterface" type="MyApplication.IInterface`1, MyApplication" />
      <typeAlias alias="App1" type="MyApplication.App1Control, MyApplication" />
    </typeAliases>
    <containers>
      <container> 
        <types>
          <type type="myInterface" mapTo="App1" name="Application 1">
            <lifetime type="singleton"/>
          </type>
        </types>
      </container>
    </containers>
  </unity>
```

The app runs fine but, the following code gives a InvalidCastException

```
container.Resolve<IInterface<UserControl>>("Application 1");
```

The error message is  :

> Unable to cast object of type 'MyApplication.App1Control' to type 'MyApplication.IInterface`1[System.Windows.Forms.UserControl]'

I believe there is a minor mistake in my code ... but am not able to figure out what. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Miguel,

  There was a mistake in the definition of my App1Control.
  The issue was fixed when I changed the definition from


  public partial class App1Control : UserControl, myInterface<App1Control>


  ..... to ......



  public partial class App1Control : UserControl, myInterface<UserControl>

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer and accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

from a comment from the OP [Sunny D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314835/sunny-d):

There was a mistake in the definition of my App1Control. The issue was fixed when I changed the definition from:

```
public partial class App1Control : UserControl, myInterface<App1Control>
```

to:

```
public partial class App1Control : UserControl, myInterface<UserControl>
```